# Seeking Advice On .NET Signing Regimen/Strategy

Tags: .net, code-signing, strongname

I'm looking for some top-level guidance on managing Visual Studio .NET application signing.

We have a growing number of applications including desktop, wrapper libraries, plug-ins, etc. Everything is .NET, usually VB but increasingly C#, though that really doesn’t matter.

To date, we've been signing assemblies using VS-generated application-specific *Personal Information Exchange* (`.pfx`) files, named after the application (eg "TheProduct.pfx"). (These require a password, otherwise a `.snk` file is generated.)

But after having a recent need to re-sign an assembly (after obfuscation), spending some hours working out why `SignTool` was [throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540555/signing-cab-file-with-signtool-not-working-any-more-the-signers-certificate-is) when trying to use the VS-generated certificate and having to create one from scratch, it's occurred to me that maybe we should get more serious about this.

Right now, my thinking is in one or two directions, either

1. Create a universal certificate to be used for *all* applications henceforth, or
2. Stick with the current application-specific certificate regimen but harden up the certs a bit by using `MakeCert/Pvk2Pfx` to ensure that they can be used by `SignTool` if ever the need arises (again).

(We would obviously use `MakeCert/Pvk2Pfx` in the universal case as well.)

Also, I'm wondering about the best "structure" to use. For example, using `SHA256` or `SHA512` instead of `SHA1`, increasing the key length to 2048 or even 4096 (1024 is the minimum acceptable at the time of writing), using a dedicated super-password (ie something generated and long), etc.

BTW, I'm specifically mentioning `.pfx` over `.snk` due to the ability to use passwords with the former. But I'm open to advice here as well. One thing we likely wouldn't go with is expiring certificates from an authority such as *Comodo*; we don’t like the idea of our products dying on a customer one New Year's Eve!

So, please let me know you thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Is this only for internal use at a company?  Since our (native C++) applications are used by customers outside of our company we have a "real" code signing certificate from Thwate (plain not Extended Validation). Note, this is wrong, at least for EXEs: "One thing we likely wouldn't go with is expiring certificates from an authority such as Comodo;..." -- if signed with a time stamp, the signature does NOT expire when the certificate does.  If signed in 2016 with a 2016 cert it is still valid in 2099.

Comment: Thanks @DaveS. The applications are commercial, public but this kid of thing has crept on us. Do you feel like providing a complete answer to the question? I assume you use this single cert for all your apps, no? Thanks also for the clarification on expiry.

Answer (score 0):

At work we have only unmanaged / native applications written in C++, so the details on signing the application itself will be a bit different.

We use a single plain (not EV) SHA-256 code-signing certificate from Thawte for all applications.  There is no need for multiple certs because one cert is all that's needed to prove these three things:

- the application was signed by someone at our company.
- the application was signed at a specific date-time (we currently get the timestamp from the server http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp ).
- the application has not been altered by even one byte since it was signed * .

Using a single certificate also helps to build up trust more quickly with Microsoft's SmartScreen security and possibly other security code.

Signature expiration: if a signature tool such as MS' SignTool is supplied with a valid time server URL, then the timestamp becomes part of the signature.  When that happens the signature does not expire when the certificate expires, it is valid "forever."

Example signature with timestamp:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\SignTool.exe" sign /f c:\thawte256\cert256.pfx /p mypassword /as /fd sha256 /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp  /v "C:\VS17\AppNamee\Release\AppName.exe"
```

The same code signing certificate can also be used with setup applications such as InstallShield to sign the MSI or EXE it creates.

* I realize there are theoretical attacks against signatures where different content is generated that hashes to the same value, but that's not a real-world concern for normal use.